# npm bower install fails (hangs at same spot)

Tags: node.js, npm, bower, bower-install

I am have been attempting to install bower repeatedly for days. The install hang at the same point -

```
 npm verb about to build C:\Users\spjbd\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\no
de_modules\insight
npm info build C:\Users\spjbd\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_module
s\insight
npm verb linkStuff [ true,
npm verb linkStuff   'C:\\Users\\spjbd\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules',
npm verb linkStuff   false,
npm verb linkStuff   'C:\\Users\\spjbd\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\bow
er\\node_modules' ]
npm info linkStuff insight@0.4.3
npm verb linkBins insight@0.4.3
npm verb linkMans insight@0.4.3
npm verb rebuildBundles insight@0.4.3
npm verb rebuildBundles [ '.bin',
npm verb rebuildBundles   'async',
npm verb rebuildBundles   'chalk',
npm verb rebuildBundles   'configstore',
npm verb rebuildBundles   'inquirer',
npm verb rebuildBundles   'lodash.debounce',
npm verb rebuildBundles   'object-assign',
npm verb rebuildBundles   'os-name',
npm verb rebuildBundles   'tough-cookie' ]
npm info install insight@0.4.3
npm info postinstall insight@0.4.3
npm verb unlock done using C:\Users\spjbd\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\insig
ht-46285e0bf21e5a96.lock for C:\Users\spjbd\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bow
er\node_modules\insight
```

I have tried several different methods to counteract -

- uninstall/reinstall node
- update npm
- add path to path variables
- etc.

An additional error that has come up is that the build has had issues with the npm-cache directory.

Any insight to getting bower running correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying this with `node@0.12`?  If so, can you try with `node@0.10.36`, which is a known-good version?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the registry helped me for hanging installs. Simply run

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

You may need to use sudo to alter your config file though.

Comment: does not helps for me

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Windows 10 and I had similar issue. Instead of using Windows command prompt for `npm install -g bower`, I used git bash command prompt. It worked.